# Efficient way to compare two lists remembering the origin for every unique element

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Given this sample, which finds unique elements while being available to tell the element source

```py
source_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
diff_list = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "six", "seven"]

source_unique = []
diff_unique = []

for entry in source_list:
    if entry not in diff_list:
        source_unique.append(entry)

for entry in diff_list:
    if entry not in source_list:
        diff_unique.append(entry)

print("Unique elements in source_list: {0}".format(source_unique))
print("Unique elements in diff_list: {0}".format(diff_unique))

###
# Unique elements in source_list: ['five']
# Unique elements in diff_list: ['zero', 'six', 'seven']
```

is there a more efficient way to do this instead of using two additional lists and all that stuff? The main task is to be able to tell the elements' origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `set`s and taking their `difference` which has a complexity of [`O(len(set_object))`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity):

```
>>> s1, s2 = set(source_list), set(diff_list)
>>> s1.difference(s2)
{'five'}
>>> s2.difference(s1)
{'seven', 'six', 'zero'}
```

Which can also be written as:

```
>>> s1 - s2 
{'five'}
>>> s2 - s1
{'seven', 'six', 'zero'}
```

in this case, you might need to transform to a `list` afterwards, *if necessary* with `list(s1 - s2)` and `list(s2 - s1)` accordingly.

Or, you could do the same thing by using a `list` comprehension and making `source_list` and `diff_list` sets for fast membership testing with the `in` operator:

For the `uniques` list:

```
source_unique = [v1 for v1 in source_list if v1 not in set(diff_list)]
source_unique
['five']
```

For the `diff_unique` list:

```
diff_unique = [v1 for v1 in diff_list if v1 not in set(source_list)]
diff_unique
['zero', 'six', 'seven']
```

Which is again `O(len(list))` unless I'm mistaking my time complexities.

Comment: You'd have much better run times if you set-ified the lists beforehand (O(1) lookup times for `in`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets:

```
source_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
diff_list = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "six", "seven"]


print("Unique elements in source_list: {0}".format(set(source_list)-set(diff_list)))
print("Unique elements in diff_list: {0}".format(set(diff_list)-set(source_list)))
```

Printing out:

```
Unique elements in source_list: set(['five'])
Unique elements in diff_list: set(['seven', 'six', 'zero'])
```

Comment: Oh, this looks super easy using sets! I've found the same question, but just about the difference. Didn't figure out that I am able to find the set difference in both directions! Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: But I'll accept Jim's answer (if you don't mind) just for completeness of the contents, in case other users encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets to do it

```
source_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
diff_list = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "six", "seven"]

source_unique = list(set(source_list) -  set(diff_list))
diff_unique =  list(set(diff_list) -  set(source_list))
```